# selenium Webdriver Page Navigation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I logged in home page and from homepage to Invoice page
I Could notable  access the Radio drop down in Invoice page .
Tried to get Page Url and title . its showing Home page and home url but the code is in Invoice page.

```
Actions Inv=new Actions(driver);
WebElement invconfg=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Invoice ConfigurationToggle']"));
Inv.moveToElement(invconfg).click(invconfg).build().perform();
WebElement Vwopt=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Invoice ConfigurationDiv']/ul/li[5]/a"));
Inv.moveToElement(Vwopt).click(Vwopt).build().perform();
WebElement filetpe=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='appDetail']/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/img"));
Select filetype=new Select(filetpe);
filetype.selectByValue("ALL");
List<WebElement> howold=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//input[@type='radio']"));
System.out.println(howold.size());
howold.get(4).click();
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());'
```

Comment: please elaborate more !

Comment: I have added the code for the invoice page.

Answer (score 0):

**driver.getTitle()** : will give you Title of web page which **Webdriver** has currently focus on ! same goes with **driver.getCurrentUrl()**

Your **code** :

```
List<WebElement> howold=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//input[@type='radio']"));
System.out.println(howold.size());
howold.get(4).click();
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

**howold** is a reference of a list that contains **WebElements**.

`howold.get(4).click();` // may open a page in different tab, for that you need to switch the focus of **webdriver** to that required page.

**Code** you can use is :

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());  
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

// performs some operations on **Invoice page** like :

```
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

Then again you have to switch back to page from where you went to Invoice Page, if you want that.

```
 driver.close();
 driver.switchTo.windows(tabs.get(0));
```